# Having problems trying to render a terrain with heightfeild algorithm with C++ and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I using the heightfield terrain algorithm to build the terrain in a game I am developing. I am using C++ and OpenGL to code the game. The engine I am using comes from a book called OpenGL Game Programming.

I load my textures with the engine in a function dedicated to rendering which holds most of the OpenGL code.

To draw the terrain I have function which wraps up all of the coordinates in one place I have one for all of the objects in the terrain including the heightfield terrain. My problem is that the terrain draws at an odd angle. My original code used variables for the values passed into the array that stores the coordinates but this kept flagging up an error in the Y coordinate in the array and I could not run the code. The Y coordinate is populated by an array that is originally declared as an unsigned char pointer and the coerced into an array of type float. I have since done away with the array and variables in the Y index and replaced them with ordinary values which enables me to run the game but the terrain renders at an awkward angle. I have rendered other objects in my code such as buildings and a concrete ground and my heightfield code is pretty much similar to the other stuff I have already rendered.
I have provided a code example and a screen shot, I hope somebody has a solution to the problem.

```
void CTerrain::DrawMountains(float xPos, float yPos, float zPos)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, zPos);

    for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z; z++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < MAP_X; x++)
        {
            terrain[x][z][0] = float(x)*MAP_SCALE;
            terrain[x][z][1] = (float)((z*32+x)*3);//replaced imageData[(z*32+x)*3]; with values imageData declared as a unsigned char pointer
            terrain[x][z][2] = float(z)*MAP_SCALE;
        } 
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < 32-1; z++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (int x = 0; x < 32-1; x++) 
        {
            //draw vertex 0

            /*glColor3f(terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f);*/
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);//changed both from 0.0f to 1.0f 
            glVertex3f(terrain[x][z][0], terrain[x][z][1], terrain[x][z][2]);

            //draw vertex 1

            /*glColor3f(terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f,  terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f);*/
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z][0], terrain[x+1][z][1], terrain[x+1][z][2]);

            //draw vertex 2

            /*glColor3f(terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f);*/
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x][z+1][0], terrain[x][z+1][1], terrain[x][z+1][2]);

            //draw vertex 3

            /*glColor3f(terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f);*/
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);//changed both from 1.0f to 0.0f
            glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z+1][0], terrain[x+1][z+1][1], terrain[x+1][z+1][2]); 

            glEnd(); //added both glEnd and glPopMatrix
        glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

Screen shot of the terrain rendering:

[image: screen shot of the terrain rendering]

#### Update

Thanks Rabbid76 for your answer and explanation. I understand I have created a linear equation by taking out the variable `MAP_Z` out of the Y geometry but I did that to make the code work. I tried your code but it again flagged up an erroe in the Y coordinates in the terrain array. I have supplied my original code , to see if you or anybody can tell me why it keeps flagging up an error in the Y coordinates in the terrain array using imageData. `MAP_X`, `MAP_Z`, and `MAP_SCALE` are all declared as macros and imageData is declared as a unsigned char pointer

```
void CTerrain::DrawMountains(float xPos, float yPos, float zPos)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z; z++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < MAP_X; x++)
        {
            terrain[x][z][0] = float(x)*MAP_SCALE;
            terrain[x][z][1] = (float) imageData[(z*MAP_Z+x)*3];
            terrain[x][z][2] = float(z)*MAP_SCALE;
        } 
    }

    glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, zPos);

    for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z-1; z++)   
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (int x = 0; x < MAP_X-1; x++) 
        {
            //draw vertex 0

            glColor3f(terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z][1]/255.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x][z][0], terrain[x][z][1], terrain[x][z][2]);

            //draw vertex 1

            glColor3f(terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f,  terrain[x+1][z][1]/255.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z][0], terrain[x+1][z][1], terrain[x+1][z][2]);

            //draw vertex 2

            glColor3f(terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x][z+1][1]/255.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x][z+1][0], terrain[x][z+1][1], terrain[x][z+1][2]);

            //draw vertex 3

            glColor3f(terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f, terrain[x+1][z+1][1]/255.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z+1][0], terrain[x+1][z+1][1], terrain[x+1][z+1][2]);

        }
        glEnd(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why, what value do I give maxHeight.

Comment: Hi Rabbid76, it is not really an error message but the debugger stops at the Y coordinate line and flags up a message saying Unhandled Exception. Access violation reading location. imageData is type char. Tried changing MAP_Z to MAP_X still doesn't work it is MAP_Z in the example code I am using.

Comment: Hi Rabbid76, just picked this up, I am not sure what you mean by the format of the content of imageData, it is a bitmap image 128px by 128px. I tried your fix above and it didn't work. I have just noticed that imageData is showing up as a bad ptr in the autos window of visual studio. Would be grateful for some help.